React Google tags tooltip show numbers in western system
 import React from "react"; import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";  class BarChart extends React.Component { convertDataToChartData = (data) => { var modified_data = []; if (data == undefined) { modified_data[""] = 0; } else data.map((value) => { modified_data[value.x] = Number(value.y) ?? value.y; });  const chartData = [["Month"]]; const months = Object.keys(modified_data);  // Add months as columns chartData[0] = chartData[0].concat(months);  // Add values for each month for (let i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {   const month = months[i];   const value = modified_data[month];   const column = [month];    // Set value for the corresponding month column   for (let j = 0; j < months.length; j++) {     column.push(j === i ? value : 0);   }    chartData.push(column); } return chartData;  };  render() { try { const { data, ishorizontal, Haxis, Vaxis,legendposition } = this.props; const chartData = this.convertDataToChartData(data);    const chartOptions = {     hAxis: { title: Haxis },     vAxis: { title: Vaxis },     legend: { position: legendposition },     isStacked: true,     series: {},     orientation: ishorizontal ? "horizontal" : "vertical",     animation: {       startup: true,       easing: "linear",       duration: 300,     },   };    for (let i = 1; i < chartData[0].length; i++) {     const month = chartData[0][i];     chartOptions.series[i - 1] = {       visibleInLegend: data == undefined ? false : true,       labelInLegend: month,     };   }    return (     <div>       <Chart         chartType="ColumnChart"         width="100%"         height="300px"         data={chartData}         options={chartOptions}       />     </div>   ); } catch (e) {}  } }  export default BarChart; 

enter image description here I want the tooltip to display numbers in indian system

This is a very poor way of asking a question.
Your code is not formatted, not shared the data you are passing and no images.
It's not possible to recreate your issue.
however, what i can suggest you here is to look into data formatting
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#data-format
specially hAxis.format
and numberFormat api.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat
'#,##,###' formats 12345 as '12,345' and 123456789 as '12,34,56,789'

